What would happen if a human completely disappeared?
How strong effect would roughly human sized and shaped vacuum spontaneously appearing at sea level have?
This event is completely fictional.
This is related to:
What would happen if a piece of matter, in our atmosphere, were to suddenly vanish?
It says that the space would be filled with speed-of-sound air particles, however, what would that effect actually create? A loud sound? A large gust? Shockwave?

This is not really an answerable question because things don't just disappear. Transformations occur, but what process could transform a human being into a vacuum state piece? None that we're aware of, I think. Any such vacuum would be immediately filled in by the surrounding air particles.

@Wookie Correct. This is a completely fictional event. Same as all those textbook exercises about balls with too high of a volume to be made out of any real material or car tires that are able to roll without friction.

@ingotangjingle No. The textbook exercises are unrealistic but do not violate the laws of physics. Your example does as it violates conservation of stress-energy.

In other words, you are asking what the effect would be of a roughly human sized (and shaped?) vacuum spontaneously appearing at sea level? It's
called cavitation! Creation of low pressure zones. .. that's what snapping shrimps do to kill their prey. .. why did you write it in such twisted manner?

@ingotangjingle anyway, it's not going to reopen, even if it does then certainly it will be marked duplicate (you have provided a link good enough for that) - let it be. .. cavitation causes similar effects in pipelines, bubbles disappear suddenly creating shockwaves strong enough to corroded metals, it sounds like stones are running down the pipe, same thing will happen here too, lots of sound and powerful shockwave.

Lightning does something like this. It heats the air around it strongly. The air expands. The lightning vanishes. The air cools rapidly. The result is thunder.

Some vacuums are inside thick glass bell jars. If the bell jar broke, it would be similar to what you are asking.

@mmesser314 - although in vacuum system failure the major issue is flying shrapnel (glass, metal, ...). The total PV energy is not super large.

@Wookie :  "This is not really an answerable question because things don't just disappear".  But it's perfectly possible, though astronomically unlikely, for a human sized vacuum to form spontaneously, or, per mmesser314's comment, for a bell jar to break.  This can easily be read as a perfectly answerable question.

The energy would not be very large.  The energy involved would be the force done by the atmosphere on the empty space.  For energy purposes, the shape doesn't matter, so we can take all of humanity, and treat them as one piston.  The volume of all of humanity is 470 million cubic meters.  So if we treated them as a piston with an area of 1 square meter , it would be 470 million meters tall.  Ignore the fact that that's taller than the atmosphere.  Using a 1 meter piston, however physically impractical, makes the calculation easier.  This is because atmospheric pressure is 101325 Pa, and when multiplied be 1 square meter that's 101.325kN.  We can round to 100kN.  That atmospheric pressure is for sea level.l and not everyone is at sea level.  This will be a bit of a overestimate, in fact.
So we can use the definition of work as force times distance to get an amount of work of 100kN*470000000m which is 47 TJ (terrajoules)
Tera is a scary prefix.  But just how big is it.  Thanks to wikipedias page of orders of magnitude (energy) we see some things to compare to:  63 TJ is the energy released by the Little Boy atomic bomb over Hiroshima.  Atomic bombs are not to be taken lightly, but compare to mother nature, they're a pittance.  A hurricane released over 1000 TJ of energy every second.
Now this would be a fast release of energy.  It would be in the form of a shockwave that can shatter brittle things like glass.  We might cause some rocks to fracture.  But in general, mother nature would not notice the sudden cacophony of our disappearance.

Another comparison - the energy released by the 1980 Mount St. Helens eruption was about $100$ PJ, which is $100,000$ TJ.

what about a single human? It would just make a quiet pop?

It would still be loud.  It would release about 6kJ of energy.  That's something like 30 or 40 firecrackers worth of energy, so it would at least be noisy.  But you can imagine a few dozen firecrackers doesn't do all that much damage (unless you are careless and ignore firecracker safety)

The answer to your question is shown every day with lightening.  A bolt of lightening heats the air to 5 times hotter than the surface of the sun. This would cause nearly all the molecules of air to move out of the way, creating the vacuum that you envision.  So what happens after that?  The surrounding air fills the vacuum and creates thunder and a shock wave.
